# Items not getting store in databse after submit

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am building this website in Django where I am storing locations as "items" inside a databse. Users are allowed to enter a detailed view of each location, and then press a "Rate" button which should open a form that lets them enter a rating. Later I want to display on each location an average of the users s ratings. I Stored the rating of users with respect to an object in a database called "Ratings". However, when I submit, items don t get stored in the "ratings".
This is the views file:

```
`from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import Item
from .forms import RateItemForm

# Create your views here.


def detail(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk = pk)

    related_items = Item.objects.filter(category = item.category, is_sold = False).exclude(pk=pk).order_by('-price')[0:3]

    items = Item.objects.filter(is_sold = False).order_by('-price')[0:6]
    highest_rated_item = items.first()

    return render(request, 'item/detail.html', {
        'item': item,
        'related_items' : related_items,
        'highest_rated_item' : highest_rated_item
    })

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def rate(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk = pk)


    if request.method == "POST":

        form = RateItemForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            rating = form.save(commit=False)
            rating.user = request.user
            rating.item = item
            rating.save()
            return redirect('item:detail', pk = rating.id)
    
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = RateItemForm()

    return render(request, 'item/rate.html', {
        'item': item,
        'form' : form,
    })`
```

The models file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    

    class Meta:
        # verbose_name = _("Category")
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse("Category_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})


class Item(models.Model):
    
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name = "items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'item_images', blank = True, null=True)
    is_sold = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # class Meta:
    #     verbose_name = _("Item")
    #     verbose_name_plural = _("Items")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse("Item_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField() 

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.name
```

The forms file

```
from django import forms

from .models import Item, Rating

class RateItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ('rating',)

    rating = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'placeholder' : 'Your rating',
    'class' : 'w-full py-4 px-6 rounded-xl border'
    }))
```

And the urls file

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'item'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>rating/', views.rate, name='rate')
]
```

Also, the rate.html file

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block title %} Rating {{ item.name }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="grid grid-cols-5 gap-3">

    <div class="col-span-3"> 
        <img src="{{item.image.url}}" class="rounded-xl">
    </div>


    <div class="col-span-2 p-6 bg-gray-100 rounded-xl flex flex-col ">
        <h1 class="text-center text-3xl mb-6">Rating: {{item.name}}</h1>


        <div class="text-justify text-gray-500 overflow-y-auto">
            <form action="." method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="inline-block mb-2">Your rating</label> <br>
                    {{form.rating}}
                </div>

                {% if form.errors or form.non_field_errors %}
                    <div class="mb-3 p-6 bg-red-100 rounded-xl">
                        {% for field in form %}
                            {{field.errors}}
                        {% endfor %}

                        {{form.non_field_errors}}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}

                
            <button class="mt-6 bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-700 rounded-xl text-lg px-6 py-3 text-white">Submit</button>


            </form>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I am expecting each item to be stored in the database so i can process them later. Now I am getting this error: "
Exception Value:
NOT NULL constraint failed: item_rating.location_id" after I played a bit with the primary key but before that it wasn t working anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your `location` field does not seem to be rendered, therefore it's not passed with the form submit request.

You either need to include location fields in your form:

```
class RateItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ('rating', 'location',)
```

or assign location object manually when saving `Rating` model:

```
rating = form.save(commit=False)
rating.user = request.user
rating.location = item
rating.save()
```

Seem like you most likely made a mistake and you're trying to assign `item` object to `rating.item` instead of `rating.location`, hence the error.